# How to encircle Invalid data in Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-office

I want to show a circle around only invalid data.

i have done the complete steps shown in this [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/display-or-hide-circles-around-invalid-data-HP005200840.aspx)

But this circle shown is very big and covers the entire cell.
I want a small circle only covering the data not the entire cell's width.

Answer (score 0):

Data validation is a built in Excel functionality. It checks whole cell value.

So it is not possible, using Data validation, to accomplish what your trying.

It MAY BE POSSIBLE using VBA, shapes, events and (hard) parsing character rendering. In your place, I would be glad with this very big circles!!! :)

Comment: is this possible that i have a designed circle. and i show that up on invalid data. Not the built in big circle or show a checkbox in front of valid and a cross in front of invalid data

Comment: It's easy to place a circle over a cell. Hard is to get circle over certain character(s).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @LS_dev.  See this [MS Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213773) about changing data validation for printing.  Try modifying it to loop through all your data validation and change the width and height.

You can probably do it with this part of the code by changing the width and height:

```
If Not c.Validation.Value Then
       Set o = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, _
           c.Left - 2, c.Top - 2, c.Width + 4, c.Height + 4)
       o.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
       o.Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 10
       o.Line.Weight = 1.25
```